# Python hdfscli - Server IPC version 9 cannot communicate with client version 4

Tags: python, python-3.x, hadoop, hdfs, urllib

I am trying to connect from Python to an Hadoop cluster that is running locally and I keep getting this error:
`requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', BadStatusLine('\x00\x00\x00\x7f~\x08ÿÿÿÿ\x0f\x10\x02\x18\t")org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$VersionMismatch*>Server IPC version 9 cannot communicate with client version`

Here is my code:
`from hdfs import Config

class HDFSClient:
_instance = None

```
def __init__(self, env):
    self._client = Config().get_client(env)

def write_data(self, data, hdfs_filename):
    """
    Write data to an HDFS file.
    """
    pass

def write_data_stream(self, iterator, hdfs_filename):
    """
    Write data to an HDFS file.
    Data is retrieved iteratively from @iterator.
    """
    self._client.write(hdfs_filename, iterator)

@staticmethod
def get_instance(env="dev"):
    if HDFSClient._instance:
        return HDFSClient._instance
    HDFSClient._instance = HDFSClient(env)
    return HDFSClient._instance`
```

And my config file is very simple also:

```
[global]
default.alias = dev

[dev.alias]
url = http://localhost:9000

[prod.alias]
url = http://localhost:9000
```

Here is the full error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Julien\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\Lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 436, in _make_request
    httplib_response = conn.getresponse(buffering=True)
TypeError: getresponse() got an unexpected keyword argument 'buffering'
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Julien\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\Lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 699, in urlopen
    httplib_response = self._make_request(
  File "C:\Users\Julien\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\Lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 445, in _make_request
    six.raise_from(e, None)
  File "<string>", line 3, in raise_from
    # Permission is hereby granted, free of charge, to any person obtaining a copy
  File "C:\Users\Julien\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\Lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 440, in _make_request
    httplib_response = conn.getresponse()
  File "C:\Users\Julien\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\Lib\http\client.py", line 1347, in getresponse
    response.begin()
  File "C:\Users\Julien\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\Lib\http\client.py", line 307, in begin
    version, status, reason = self._read_status()
  File "C:\Users\Julien\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\Lib\http\client.py", line 289, in _read_status
    raise BadStatusLine(line)
http.client.BadStatusLine: 

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Julien\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\Lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 439, in send
    resp = conn.urlopen(
  File "C:\Users\Julien\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\Lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 755, in urlopen
    retries = retries.increment(
  File "C:\Users\Julien\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\Lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\retry.py", line 531, in increment
    raise six.reraise(type(error), error, _stacktrace)
  File "C:\Users\Julien\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\Lib\site-packages\urllib3\packages\six.py", line 734, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "C:\Users\Julien\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\Lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 699, in urlopen
    httplib_response = self._make_request(
  File "C:\Users\Julien\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\Lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 445, in _make_request
    six.raise_from(e, None)
  File "<string>", line 3, in raise_from
    # Permission is hereby granted, free of charge, to any person obtaining a copy
  File "C:\Users\Julien\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\Lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 440, in _make_request
    httplib_response = conn.getresponse()
  File "C:\Users\Julien\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\Lib\http\client.py", line 1347, in getresponse
    response.begin()
  File "C:\Users\Julien\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\Lib\http\client.py", line 307, in begin
    version, status, reason = self._read_status()
  File "C:\Users\Julien\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\Lib\http\client.py", line 289, in _read_status
    raise BadStatusLine(line)
urllib3.exceptions.ProtocolError: ('Connection aborted.', BadStatusLine('\x00\x00\x00\x7f~\x08ÿÿÿÿ\x0f\x10\x02\x18\t")org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$VersionMismatch*>Server IPC version 9 cannot communicate with client version 470\x0e:\x00@\x01Hõ*'))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Julien\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2464, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "C:\Users\Julien\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2450, in wsgi_app
    response = self.handle_exception(e)
  File "C:\Users\Julien\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1867, in handle_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "C:\Users\Julien\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\Lib\site-packages\flask\_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
    raise value
  File "C:\Users\Julien\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2447, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "C:\Users\Julien\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1952, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "C:\Users\Julien\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1821, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "C:\Users\Julien\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\Lib\site-packages\flask\_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
    raise value
  File "C:\Users\Julien\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1950, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "C:\Users\Julien\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1936, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "C:\Users\Julien\Documents\Travail\PanoptesTechnologies\block-analysis-backend\api\src\with_cors.py", line 12, in decorated_function
    return f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Julien\Documents\Travail\PanoptesTechnologies\block-analysis-backend\api\utils\log.py", line 37, in decorated
    return f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Julien\Documents\Travail\PanoptesTechnologies\block-analysis-backend\api\app.py", line 154, in heuristic
   #=======================================================================================================================
File "C:\Users\Julien\Documents\Travail\PanoptesTechnologies\block-analysis-backend\api\utils\hadoop.py", line 21, in write_data_stream
    self._client.write(hdfs_filename, iterator)
  File "C:\Users\Julien\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\Lib\site-packages\hdfs\client.py", line 459, in write
    res = self._create(
  File "C:\Users\Julien\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\Lib\site-packages\hdfs\client.py", line 125, in api_handler
    raise err
  File "C:\Users\Julien\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\Lib\site-packages\hdfs\client.py", line 102, in api_handler
    res = client._request(
  File "C:\Users\Julien\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\Lib\site-packages\hdfs\client.py", line 209, in _request
    return self._session.request(
  File "C:\Users\Julien\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\Lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 542, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Julien\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\Lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 655, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Julien\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\Lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 498, in send
    raise ConnectionError(err, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', BadStatusLine('\x00\x00\x00\x7f~\x08ÿÿÿÿ\x0f\x10\x02\x18\t")org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$VersionMismatch*>Server IPC version 9 cannot communicate with client version 470\x0e:\x00@\x01Hõ*'))
```

Python version: 3.8
hdfscli version: 2.6.0
Hadoop version: 3.2.1

I already checked packages version needed by hdsfcli.

Is there something I can try to solve this?
Thank you for your help.

Best regads,

Answer (score 1):

Welp, I had the same struggle.
For context:
This package uses the webhdfs API. On other versions, it was running on the 50070 port, but for Hadoop 3.2.1 and 3.3.1 (my version), it is running on the 9870 port.

Just change:

```
[dev.alias]
url = http://localhost:9000

[prod.alias]
url = http://localhost:9000
```

To:

```
[dev.alias]
url = http://localhost:9870

[prod.alias]
url = http://localhost:9870
```

And you're golden.